# Filter data in Google Sheets spreadsheet for me only, not any other shared users / viewers

Tags: google-sheets

We have a "Google Drive Spreadsheet" that 4 team members use. (User A, B, C, D)

Users need to apply filters to the spreadsheet, but from time 2 or more users are trying to filter the spreadsheet at once. This causes issues as they may be trying to filter the data to review it / analyse it on different things.

Is it possible User A filter data in a way that it will only be visible to User A, but if User B, C, D where in the spreadsheet they would see the unfiltered data and be able to create their own filters which would in turn no impact upon other users either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the users define "Filter views" through the Data -> Filter Views menu. See [Create, name, and save a filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681#filter_view)

Basically, this creates a filtered view which only one user sees, and several users can have different filter views active on the same data at the same time.